# move_uploaded_file is returning false, despite 777 priority on the upload directory and file upload on in the php.ini

Tags: php, html, upload

Things I have checked:

- upload_max_filesize
- file_uploads = On
- directory's permissions are 777
- checking the file actually uploads

Here's my html form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file to upload:
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here's a simplified of upload.php:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
else {
    echo "Upload successful.<br>";
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], "var/www/html/pictures/" . basename($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]))) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.<br>";
}
else {
    echo "Error: ", PHP_EOL;
    print_r(error_get_last());
    exit;
}
?>
```

And here's the output I get:

> Upload successful.
>   Error: Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpDelzbW' to 'var/www/html/pictures/archer.jpg' [file] => /var/www/html/upload.php [line] => 13 )

Answer (score 0):

now if you had just looked in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
>
> Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

you need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 99M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 99M
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified when I "checked upload_max_filesize" I also checked post_max_size. Both are set to 10M and the file im testing is less than 1M

Comment: @Zingy yes its error code **2** which only means one thing

Comment: I tried even manually changing the html form to have a size limit built in: using
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="{1024 * (1024 * 10)}">
but nothing changed.

Comment: check `phpinfo()` for the actual values in use and `value="{1024 * (1024 * 10)}` is not a valid value

Comment: phpinfo() returns 10M but that shouldn't be an issue, since the error references the html form rather than the php.ini 

Also my bad, the file is (1024 * (1024 * 10)) but I retyped it for this.

I'm confused because it tells me the file properly uploaded but the upload form is rejecting it (not the script)